# Make rebar compile .core files in erlang project

Tags: erlang, elixir, rebar, beam, rebar3

I am an absolute Erlang newbie and I wonder if it is possible for `rebar` to compile `.core` files using `rebar3 compile`. According to the documentation : https://www.rebar3.org/docs/commands rebar3 will only compile the `.app.src` and `.erl` files. And I can see that when I build my project the `.core` files are ignored. I would appreciate any help with this. Thanks

Comment: I have no idea what `.core` files are, but I’d guess you are to introduce the [custom compiler plugin](https://www.rebar3.org/docs/custom-compiler-plugins) for `rebar3`.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin Erlang has a core language called `Core Erlang` - https://www.it.uu.se/research/group/hipe/cerl/doc/core_erlang-1.0.3.pdf

If you take simple erlang program and compile it using `erlc +to_core myprog.erl`  it will emit a `myprog.core` file